# ST_MakePoint(long, lat) HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I am trying to convert a normal table containing coordinates value to a geospatial data table .Which will contain  geometry column too .

For additional information I created table as

```
 create table latLng(
 lat varchar,
 long varchar);
```

> `alter table latLng add column geom geometry(Point,4326);
>   UPDATE latLng SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);`

[image: My Latitude Longitude table]

```
ERROR:  function st_makepoint(character varying, character varying) does not 
exist
LINE 1: UPDATE latLng SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat):...
                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need 
to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What the types of `lat` and `long` fields in your `latLng` table? Looks like Postgresql is saying they are text, not numbers.

Comment: Type of lat and long is float

Comment: Sorry its string only. How should I convert them to float or numeric ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ERROR:  function st_makepoint(**character varying**, **character varying**) does not 
>   exist

says it all, your `lat` and `lon` are of type varchar.

but the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) tells:

> geometry ST_MakePoint(**double precision** x, **double precision** y);

**Solution:**

> Hint: [...] You might need to add explicit type casts.

The Hint tells you what to do: Try to cast as double:

```
UPDATE latLng SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long::double precision, lat::double precision), 4326) where lat <> '' and lon <> '';
```

**Or** update your original table within your query:

```
alter table latLng alter column lat type double precision using lat::double precision;
alter table latLng alter column long type double precision using long::double precision;
```

---

When you receive the following error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""

You have empty strings in your table. Try to update empty strings to *NULL* in your table before altering the column.

```
update latLng set lat = null WHERE lat = '';
update latLng set long = null WHERE long = '';
```

Comment: It giving error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` I tried both of your solutions

Comment: I changed the answer to use double precision instead

Comment: That is probably easier than faffing with numerics, when you are going to end up with a geom anyway.

Comment: @RoVo Again for double precision `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
`this error

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I am getting error for trying that only

Comment: okay, you have some empty values...  `select ''::double precision;` gives the same error.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer once again how to fix that error in your table and also in your query.

Comment: Its done I got the results  @RoVo

Comment: next time create your table with `double precision` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS extension missing?

I went through the same error, even after converting longitude and latitude from character varying to double precision. 
The problem was simple, the database had not been set up with PostGIS extensions installed, and so ST_MakePoint didn't exist.
For info, if the geom wants to be exported to GIS, ST_SetSRID and ST_transform need to be used to get the right SRID:

ST_transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(a.longitude, a.latitude),4326),3857) as geom
From name_of_table as a

Comment: in my case i already had the extension setup, but it for some reason didn't work, after two hours searching i deleted the extension and created it again, then it worked !.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue and traced it back to the default install location of the PostGIS extension being in the public schema.

Prefixing all of the PostGIS types with `public` made it work for me; try checking where your PostGIS install is actually located.  For instance:

```
alter table latLng add column geom public.geometry(Point,4326);
UPDATE latLng SET geom = public.ST_SetSRID(public.ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);
```

The data types need to be `double precision` for `ST_MakePoint` of course, but this same error appeared exactly the same way when it was just missing the schema prefix for the functions and type casts (even with lat/lon as `double precision`).

Answer (score 0):

Please also make sure you have enabled the POSTGIS extension.

1. Install the PostGIS, follow the instructions for your operating system at https://postgis.net/install
2. Then, to enable it on your database you can do:

   CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

Answer (score 0):

update table_name set <geometry_column>= st_transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long::double precision, lat::double precision), 4326),3857)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).